# Kerberos/SPNEGO authentication through Apache to Cherrypy

Tags: apache, kerberos, windows-authentication, cherrypy, spnego

We are wanting the ability to provide seamless single-sign-on into our web application. Our users are all using a modern version of IE and they will be accessing our website locally within an intranet, they will all be logged into Windows with AD accounts.

It seems that we can use integrated windows authentication to have the browser pass through the credentials, so this side looks fine.

But on the server side we have Apache 2.2 (hosted on Windows Server 2008+) with CherryPy sitting behind it - we use Rewrite rules to pass requests into CherryPy.

I have managed to find a windows compiled version of mod_spnego for Apache 2.2 (https://github.com/ibauersachs/mod_spnego) and I believe I have this configured in some way to authenticate the clients using their AD credentials.

However, we need to get these users details through to CherryPy somehow as we need to obtain further AD details over LDAP to apply permissions in our application (something that we already do but with simple username/password authentication first). This is where I have hit a dead end as I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I've seen various talk about the REMOTE_USER environment variable and suggestions for setting an extended header with the information we need in Apache but none of this seems to work.

Could anyone help me understand how to go about this? Apologies if I've not described everything correctly above, as I say I am new to Kerberos/SPNEGO and may be missing something obvious, or trying to overcomplicate things, potentially.

Comment: A duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922805/spnego-kerberos-token-generation-validation-for-sso-using-python

Comment: I'd seen this question previously but it doesn't seem to be the same question I am asking, I can already handle the authentication in Apache, I just need the details passed through to CherryPy as well. I could do the authentication itself in CherryPy too but the example in that question doesn't have any documentation or explanation as to how this would be done.

Comment: I've never done this so my question may be stupid: can't you forward AUTH_USER Apache server var (which is set by mod_spnego) to CherryPy?

Comment: Yeah we have figured out a way of getting the REMOTE_USER var in using a extended request header, sort of does what we want so it's a start!